# How to retrieve all records from Dataextension without default value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How to retrieve all records from data extension without default values in ampscript.

I want to return all rows with the field name where `FieldName` is a picklist value

```
var @stage = AttributeValue("FieldName")

%%=v(@stage)=%%
```

But it is not returning any rows

Comment: try with ssjs script it is easy for retrieving the records from dataextension without using default value

Comment: Can u please post a sample code for retriving picklist values in ampscript

Comment: where did you get the pick list value ? or  from  form?

Comment: Please update your question and include the additional code for your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to retrieve all records in a Data Extension you can do so in two ways.

1. Add a column in your Data Extension with a default value of "1".

As an example, you can create a column called "include" and with a default value of "1".

In your email or landing page you can use the following AMPScript to retrieve all records

```
%%[

SET @RECORDS = LOOKUPROWS("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME", "include", "1")

]%%
```

More information on the LookupRows Method can be found on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm)

2. Using Server Side Javascript will allow you to retrieve all records without the need to add a new column to the Data Extension. The following code is **not recommended** to be used in an email

   var DE = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME");

   var records = DE.rows.retrieve();

More information on the SSJS method can be found on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm)